# Openshift configure "Request Header" authentication

Tags: authentication, openshift, request-headers

I want to configure Openshift authentication through **Request Header**. I have tried modifying the **master-config.yaml** file as mentioned at [Request Header](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/admin_guide/configuring_authentication.html#RequestHeaderIdentityProvider) but it's giving certificate errors so I need help on how to bypass error or how to get the certificates supported by Openshift. I updated only following stanza.

```
  identityProviders:
  - challenge: true
    login: true
    mappingMethod: claim
    name: my_request_header_provider
    provider:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: RequestHeaderIdentityProvider
      challengeURL: https://host:port/api/user/oauth/authorize?${query}
      loginURL: https://host:port/api/user/oauth/authorize?${query}
      headers:
      - x-auth-token
```

I have used following command to restart the openshift

```
openshift start master --config=/etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/master-config.yaml
```

Getting following errors

```
 Warning: oauthConfig.identityProvider[0].provider.clientCA: Invalid value: "": if no clientCA is set, no request verification is done, and any request directly against the OAuth server can impersonate any identity from this provider, master start will continue.
Invalid MasterConfig /etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/master-config.yaml
  etcdClientInfo.urls: Required value
  kubeletClientInfo.port: Required value
  kubernetesMasterConfig.proxyClientInfo.certFile: Invalid value: "/etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/master.proxy-client.crt": could not read file: stat /etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/master.proxy-client.crt: no such file or directory
  kubernetesMasterConfig.proxyClientInfo.keyFile: Invalid value: "/etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/master.proxy-client.key": could not read file: stat /etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/master.proxy-client.key: no such file or directory
  masterClients.openShiftLoopbackKubeConfig: Invalid value: "/etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/openshift-master.kubeconfig": could not read file: stat /etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/openshift-master.kubeconfig: no such file or directory
  oauthConfig.masterCA: Invalid value: "/etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/ca.crt": could not read file: stat /etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/ca.crt: no such file or directory
  serviceAccountConfig.privateKeyFile: Invalid value: "/etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/serviceaccounts.private.key": could not read file: stat /etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/serviceaccounts.private.key: no such file or directory
  serviceAccountConfig.publicKeyFiles[0]: Invalid value: "/etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/serviceaccounts.public.key": could not read file: stat /etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/serviceaccounts.public.key: no such file or directory
  serviceAccountConfig.masterCA: Invalid value: "/etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/ca-bundle.crt": could not read file: stat /etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/ca-bundle.crt: no such file or directory
  servingInfo.certFile: Invalid value: "/etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/master.server.crt": could not read file: stat /etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/master.server.crt: no such file or directory
  servingInfo.keyFile: Invalid value: "/etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/master.server.key": could not read file: stat /etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/master.server.key: no such file or directory
  servingInfo.clientCA: Invalid value: "/etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/ca.crt": could not read file: stat /etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/ca.crt: no such file or directory
  controllerConfig.serviceServingCert.signer.certFile: Invalid value: "/etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/service-signer.crt": could not read file: stat /etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/service-signer.crt: no such file or directory
  controllerConfig.serviceServingCert.signer.keyFile: Invalid value: "/etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/service-signer.key": could not read file: stat /etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/service-signer.key: no such file or directory
  aggregatorConfig.proxyClientInfo.certFile: Invalid value: "/etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/aggregator-front-proxy.crt": could not read file: stat /etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/aggregator-front-proxy.crt: no such file or directory
  aggregatorConfig.proxyClientInfo.keyFile: Invalid value: "/etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/aggregator-front-proxy.key": could not read file: stat /etc/origin/master/reqheadauthconfig/aggregator-front-proxy.key: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things I have to share with you here.

1. for the provider.clientCA error:  ClientCA is required for RequestHeader identity provider since OpenShift api need it to verify clients which pass request with "x-auth-token" http header.
2. For all the files with "no such file or directory" error: I think you just make a copy for /etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml, but all files is in relative path format, so the error comes here.

Comment: I will try out your suggestions and let you know.